# Word for someone who has accepted something

Tags: word-usage

I was programming away today when I needed a variable name, the variable holds people who have accepted something.

So my question is, is "Acceptee" a word? And if not what is the acceptable word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OED the word *acceptee* has two senses. In the first of them it essentially means the same thing as *acceptor* (or *accepter*) - which is quite unlike the relationship between *trainer* and *trainee*.

**So in answer to the OP's question it could be *acceptor*, *accepter*, or *acceptee***.

When it comes to a person who is accepted, *acceptor* and *acceptee* stand in the same relationship to one another as *trainer* and *trainee*.

> 1. A person who accepts or agrees to something; a recipient; spec. (in early use) = acceptor n. 1c.
>
> 1942   Billboard 9 May 31/3   Response..to participation in the Army
>   and Navy War Relief Fund drive has been gratifying... Advertising
>   matter showing participation in the plan is being forwarded to all
>   acceptees.
>
> 1982   Los Angeles Times 29 Apr. vi. 1/4   The acceptees will
>   have—always in inverse proportion to the majesty of the award—a few
>   dozen thanks to give.
>
> 2. A person who is accepted; a person who gets acceptance.
>
> 1972   Afr. Stud. Rev. 15 484   Some districts seek to expand places
>   in primary schools even with formally unqualified teachers, hoping
>   thereby to assure a larger group of lucky acceptees into secondary
>   schools.
>
> 2005   H. Cloud & J. Townsend Rescue your Love Life iv. 113
>   Acceptance is based on the acceptor's love and the acceptee's need.

Answer (score 4):

I would understand an *acceptee* as a person that is accepted, not the person that accepted anything.

The *active* form would be *accepter* ([see M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepter)): *one that accepts*.

The same pattern you see in

> trainer -> trainee

Comment: Agreed, as in Merriam-Webster, accepter means one that accepts. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepter).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the person is accepting.  If a person accepts something abstract, like "terms and conditions" of an agreement, the word would be "accepter."  However, if a person accepts something like a package, the word "recipient" may be more appropriate.

Comment: The person who accepts a package might not be its intended recipient (e.g. a receptionist, as confusing as that may be)